# How to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, execute, procedure

I have created a stored procedure in sql server; which I am trying to execute in vb.net but, for some reasons it is not working. Can anyone help?

This is the procedure I created; which works fine in sql server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_CUS_ADD 
(@CATEGORY_NAME Varchar(30), @BRAND_NAME Varchar(30), @PRODUCT_DETAIL Varchar(30), @SALE_QUANTITY Numeric(9,2), @SALE_PRICE Numeric(9,2), @SALE_TOTAL_PRICE Numeric(9,2), @SALE_DATE datetime, @CUSTOMER_ID int, @PRODUCT_ID int, @CREDIT_PAYMENT bit)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SALE(SALE_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, BRAND_NAME, PRODUCT_DETAIL, SALE_QUANTITY, SALE_PRICE, SALE_TOTAL_PRICE, SALE_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, CREDIT_PAYMENT) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SALE_Sequence, @CATEGORY_NAME, @BRAND_NAME, @PRODUCT_DETAIL, @SALE_QUANTITY, @SALE_PRICE, @SALE_TOTAL_PRICE, @SALE_DATE, @CUSTOMER_ID, @PRODUCT_ID, @CREDIT_PAYMENT)
END;
```

This is the code I wrote to execute the procedure in VB.net:

```
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection("")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        cmd.Connection = cn

        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("PRC_CUS_ADD", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CATEGORY_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRAND_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRODUCT_DETAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox3.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SALE_QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value =txtQUANTITY.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SALE_PRICE", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtPRICE.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SALE_TOTAL_PRICE", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value =txtTOTAL.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ALE_DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtp.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUSTOMER_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtCustomerId.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRODUCT_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPRODUCT.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CREDIT_PAYMENT", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = credit.CheckState

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        cn.Close()
```

Please help! I just don't know what's wrong with the code. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Yes I get an error message that says: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: There's more to the error message than that.  There should be an actual description of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You have used "ExecuteReader" but in fact your procedure does not return any resultset. You should use "ExecuteNonQuery".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of dr = cmd.ExecuteReader but, I am still getting the same error message. I am wondering if it is not the sqlDBType I used for the variables?

Comment: @answerme: Without more detail from the error message, there's no hope of answering your question.  If you can't get more detail from the exception message, write some code that displays the `InnerException` property of the exception, and tell us what it says.

Comment: It worked. I used an exception catch as you suggested and found that I misspelled one of the variables. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! YOU SAVED MY DAY...